# How to add another method in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, rabl, rails-api

I am having a problem while adding a new method to a controller, here are the details:

**matches_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @matches = Match.all    
  render rabl: @matches
end

def current
  @matches = Match.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM `TEST`.`matches` where live=1;")    
  render rabl: @matches
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :matches, defaults: {format: :json}, except: :edit do 
  collection do
    get :current
  end
end
```

**current.json.rabl**

```
collection @match
   attributes :id,:live
```

**Rake routes**

```
current_matches GET    /matches/current(.:format) matches#current {:format=>:json}
        matches GET    /matches(.:format)         matches#index {:format=>:json}
                POST   /matches(.:format)         matches#create {:format=>:json}
      new_match GET    /matches/new(.:format)     matches#new {:format=>:json}
          match GET    /matches/:id(.:format)     matches#show {:format=>:json}
                PUT    /matches/:id(.:format)     matches#update {:format=>:json}
                DELETE /matches/:id(.:format)     matches#destroy {:format=>:json}
```

**Error in log**

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `flash' for #<MatchesController:0x0000000d7b2368>):
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:6:in `block in <class:ApplicationController>'
```

**application.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
   include ActionController::MimeResponds
   include CanCan::ControllerAdditions

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    flash[:error] = exception.message
    puts exception.message
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  def log_exception(exception)
    logger.error(exception.message)
    logger.error(exception.backtrace.join("\n"))
  end
end
```

I have done this before in another application I don't know why it is not working here.

Comment: Which part is not working? Are you getting a "no route" error? What does `rake routes` output?

Comment: i have edited my question please review it now

Comment: Your error is referring to a file which you have not included: application_controller.rb. Please show that file.

Comment: application.rb added now please review

Comment: It would appear that you cannot access the `flash` variable from a rescue_from block, although I've never tried it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access `flash` within a block directly passed to `rescue_from`. You can, however, access `flash` if you pass a Symbol of an exception handler method. For example:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied, :with => :access_denied

  private

  def access_denied(exception)
    flash[:error] = exception.message
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

See the [ActionController Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rescue_from) section on `rescue_from` for more details.

Comment: Your original error cited `application_controller.rb:6:in 'block in <class:ApplicationController>'`, but with my change above there should no longer be a block passed to `rescue_from` on line 6. Have you removed that block? Or else do you need to restart the app perhaps?